# Response 403 with signature does not match using presignurl s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i faced some issue when uploading the image, the signature will not match as mentioned above. Any solution to fix this?

[image: Coding]

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages**. Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: Hi John, Noted.